# Pandas - Parent child relationship - Duplicative data/Index issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to work with parent child relational data in pandas and having some issues getting the proper parent/child mapping on portions of my data.

I attempted to use ffill and fillna to no avail, but I may have conducted that incorrectly.

I have tried two methods with issues on both. Any assistance getting over this hurdle would be amazing. Thank you for your help.

code:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "child_string": ["string42","string23","string23","string54","string28","string86","string15","string1"], 
            "child": [None, 8675, 8675, 8676, 2048, 5442, 1942, 3185], 
            "parent": [None, 2048, 2048, 2048, 1942, 1942, 3185, None],
            "interesting": ["some_unique_field1", "some_unique_field2", "some_unique_field3", "some_unique_field4", "some_unique_field5", "some_unique_field6", "some_unique_field7", "some_unique_field8"]
        }
)

# This gives me the right output except for parent string for string 1 and string 42
print(df.merge(
    df[['child', 'child_string']].rename(columns={"child":"parent", "child_string": "parent_string"}), 
    on='parent', 
    how='left'
))


# This fails with an invalid index error. 
df['parent_string'] = df['parent'].map(df.set_index('child').child_string)
print(df)
```

Expected output:

```
child_string, child, parent, interesting parent_string
string42,  NaN,  NaN, some_unique_field1, NaN
string23, 8675, 2048, some_unique_field2, string28
string23, 8675, 2048, some_unique_field3, string28
string54, 8676, 2048, some_unique_field4, string28
string28, 2048, 1942, some_unique_field5, string15
string86, 5442, 1942, some_unique_field6, string15
string15, 1942, 3185, some_unique_field7,  string1
string1, 3185, NaN, some_unique_field8,  NaN
```

Comment: Why don't you use your first method and replace with `NaN` if the parent is `NaN` to solve string42 and string1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary that has the information of "child" column as `key`'s and "child_string" as values.

```
child_info = df[['child_string','child']].dropna()
child_string_to_child_dict = dict(zip(child_info.child,child_info.child_string))

>>> child_string_to_child_dict
 
{8675.0: 'string23',
 8676.0: 'string54',
 2048.0: 'string28',
 5442.0: 'string86',
 1942.0: 'string15',
 3185.0: 'string1'}
```

---

Then you can `map` that dictionary on your "parent" column

```
df['parent_string'] = df['parent'].map(child_string_to_child_dict)
```

Result:

```
  child_string   child  parent         interesting parent_string
0     string42     NaN     NaN  some_unique_field1           NaN
1     string23  8675.0  2048.0  some_unique_field2      string28
2     string23  8675.0  2048.0  some_unique_field3      string28
3     string54  8676.0  2048.0  some_unique_field4      string28
4     string28  2048.0  1942.0  some_unique_field5      string15
5     string86  5442.0  1942.0  some_unique_field6      string15
6     string15  1942.0  3185.0  some_unique_field7       string1
7      string1  3185.0     NaN  some_unique_field8           NaN
```

A similar approach to what you tried